# Why am I getting:"Option 'SINGLE_USER' cannot be set in database 'master'." when running my backend c#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

When I'm trying to run my backend application in C# that allows users to login and register accounts I'm getting the following error:

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
    IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') <> 5
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [master] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END;
    fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
          Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
          IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') <> 5
          BEGIN
              ALTER DATABASE [master] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
          END;
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
    Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Comment: Did you check whether the credentials used in EF, is sufficient to execute that SQL command?